# Borel measure of non-empty open set of a closed matrix group (Y)

Tags: measure-theory

We start with a closed matrix group G and a Borel measure $\xi$ on G with $\xi \neq 0$ and $\forall g \in G$ $\forall$ Borel $B \subset G$ holds $\xi(Bg) = \xi(B)$.

The Goal is to prove, that for every non-empty open $V \subset G$ holds $\xi(V) > 0$.

I have no idea how to solve this exercise.

Can anyone give me a hint/idea how to start this exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $G$ is a topological group with the topology defined by viewing $G$ as a subspace of the matrix set with its usual topology.

Since $G$ is closed, it is compact.

Let $V$ be a non-empty open subset of $G$.

For all $g\in G$, $Vg=f^{-1}(V)$ where $f:x\in G\mapsto xg^{-1}$ is continuous since $G$ is a topological group. So for all $g\in G$, $Vg$ is an open subset of $G$.

Let $g\in G$ and $v\in V$. Then $g=vv^{-1}g$ so $g\in V(v^{-1}g)$. Therefore,
$$
G\subset\bigcup_{x\in G}Vx.
$$

Since $G$ is compact, we deduce that there exist $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in G$ such that
$$
G\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^nVx_i.
$$

Therefore
$$
0<\xi(G)\le\sum_{i=1}^n\xi(Vx_i)=n\xi(V),
$$
hence $\xi(V)>0$.